# How to create a simple 'play a song' intent for Google Assistant using C# SDK

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am new to Google Actions SDK (or API) and I want to build a simple Google Assistant action: 'Play a fixed song when the agent is invoked'.

I went through the sdk samples (https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/actions-sdk#samples) as well as DialogFlow and Actions On Google documentation, but its difficult to understand where to start from.

I saw replies to similar questions asking to add mediaResponse intent, but am unable to find that intent or anything like that in DialogFlow or on Google.

Looking for help on how to get started to play music when the agent is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

To play music the standard Google Assistant way is indeed using a [media response](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/responses#media_responses) object. This object is build in most SDK's for Google Assistant, but I am not sure if that is the case for C#. If it isn't then you can try creating a JSON that is similar to that of a media response and use that to send music back to your user.

One other alternative would be to use [SSML's audio tag](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/reference/ssml#audio). You can provide this ssml in as speech when returning a response to the user, the only thing you have to do is host the music that you want to play somewhere using https.

Do note that ssml audio response are limited in their play time. (Max 240 seconds)

```
<speak>
  <audio src="https://actions.google.com/.../cat_purr_close.ogg">
    <desc>a cat purring</desc>
    PURR (sound didn't load)
  </audio>
</speak>
```